# Find the last vowel in a string

Tags: python, string

I cant seem to find the proper way to search a string for the last vowel, and store any unique consonants after that last vowel. I have it set up like this so far.

```
word = input('Input a word: ')
wordlow = word.lower()
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
last_vowel_index = 0

for i, ch in enumerate(wordlow):
    if ch == VOWELS:
        last_vowel_index += i

print(wordlow[last_vowel_index + 1:])
```

Comment: Why are you _adding_ `i` onto `last_vowel_index` ?

Comment: Are you talking about in the if loop, or when printing? Or hell, even both?

Comment: `last_vowel_index += i` <-- this. I can't think of any reason for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse your string, and use `itertools.takewhile` to take everything until the "last" (now the first after reversal) vowel:

```
from itertools import takewhile

out = ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x not in set('aeiou'), string[::-1]))[::-1]
print(out)
'ng'
```

If there are no vowels, the entire string is returned. Another thing to note is that, you should convert your input string to lower case using a `str.lower` call, otherwise you risk not counting uppercase vowels.

---

If you want unique consonants only (without any repetition), a further step is needed:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
out = ''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(out).keys())
```

Here, the `OrderedDict` lets us keep order while eliminating duplicates, since, the keys must be unique in any dictionary.

Alternatively, if you want consonants that *only* appear once, use:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(out)
out = ''.join(x for x in out if c[x] == 1)
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl Hmm, didn't see that. Think it should be fine now.

Comment: OP is unclear by what is meant by 'unique consonants'. Does me mean consonants that occur only 1 time after the last vowel or does he simply want to remove duplicates?

Comment: @DavidJenkins Edited. These nitpicks are easy to address.

Comment: @david Jenkins, for example if hell was input, it would just store one l

Comment: @manoman181 I think the 2nd section of my answer addresses your problem quite nicely.

Comment: @coldspeed You are correct that it is easily addressed, but that is not the point nor is it a nitpick. Clarity of requirements is essential and it is important for him to understand that. I've seen months of dev time and hundreds of thousands of dollars wasted due to lack of clarity.

Answer (score 4):

I like [COLDSPEED's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406958/find-the-last-vowel-in-a-string#answer-46407047) approach, but for completeness, I will suggest a regex based solution:

```
import re
s = 'sjdhgdfgukgdk'
re.search(r'([^AEIOUaeiou]*)$', s).group(1)
# 'kgdk'

# '[^AEIOUaeiou]'  matches a non-vowel (^ being the negation)
# 'X*'  matches 0 or more X
# '$' matches the end of the string
# () marks a group, group(1) returns the first such group
```

See the [docs on python regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Further processing is also needed for the uniqueness part ;)

Comment: Nice one. You should add a brief explanation on the regex and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a function for that:

```
def func(astr):
    vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')

    # Container for all unique not-vowels after the last vowel
    unique_notvowels = set()

    # iterate over reversed string that way you don't need to reset the index
    # every time a vowel is encountered.
    for idx, item in enumerate(astr[::-1], 1):  
        if item in vowels:
            # return the vowel, the index of the vowel and the container
            return astr[-idx], len(astr)-idx, unique_notvowels
        unique_notvowels.add(item)

    # In case no vowel is found this will raise an Exception. You might want/need
    # a different behavior...
    raise ValueError('no vowels found')
```

For example:

```
>>> func('asjhdskfdsbfkdes')
('e', 14, {'s'})

>>> func('asjhdskfdsbfkds')
('a', 0, {'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'k', 's'})
```

It returns the last vowel, the index of the vowel and all unique not-vowels after the last vowel.

In case the vowels should be ordered you need to use an ordered container instead of the set, for example a `list` (could be much slower) or `collections.OrderedDict` (more memory expensive but faster than the list).

Answer (score 0):

You can just reverse your string and loop over each letter until you encounter the first vowel:

```
for i, letter in enumerate(reversed(word)):
    if letter in VOWELS:
        break
print(word[-i:])
```

Answer (score -1):

`last_vowel` will return the last vowel in the word

`last_index` will give you the last index of this vowel in the input

Python 2.7

```
input = raw_input('Input a word: ').lower()
last_vowel = [a for a in input if a in "aeiou"][-1]
last_index = input.rfind(last_vowel)
print(last_vowel)
print(last_index)
```

Python 3.x

```
input = input('Input a word: ').lower()
last_vowel = [a for a in input if a in "aeiou"][-1]
last_index = input.rfind(last_vowel)
print(last_vowel)
print(last_index)
```